How do i update pyjwt from to 2.4.0 in Red Hat
I'm trying to upgrade pyjwt to 2.4.0 in Redhat but it throws an error timeout. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Much appreciate your inputs.
python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
pip3 install pyjwt
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
python3 -c "import jwt; print(jwt.version)"
1.6.1
h-4.4$ pip3 install --upgrade pyjwt==2.4.0
Collecting pyjwt==2.4.0
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/pyjwt/
I've tried this command curl https://pypi.org/simple/pyjwt/ . However, no output is visible.
